# U.S. Technology - Is it legal to scrape freely accessible data then charge to be able to filter that data?

Tags: united-states, internet

Would it be legal for me to sell a service that scrapes and filters the freely accessible data from sites and also provides a link back to them?

I essentially want to create a scraper that collects data from multiple sites (on demand from the user) like an aggregator but sell the service that allows the user to filter certain terms out of the data titles.

My app would scrape on request, filter, then return the results.
The data would touch my server for filtering but wouldn't be stored.

e.g. Lists of recipes from something like recipe.com, serious eats, etc but the user wants to find all recipes from every site available on the service that have marmalade in the title, but exclude all that say lemon, pineapple, and orange.

If they want to know more details about the data or the recipe, they'll have to follow the link to the site.

Comment: Why are you sure this "freely accessible data" is really free? Have you read the TOS of every site you intend to scrape?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch every tos I've read through on these sites usually pertain to the member signing in with an account and those accounts are usually made for uploading content.

Comment: So this is a search engine and you want to charge users for filtering the results?

Comment: @Lag by the legal definition of a search engine, no.  A search engine would create a database and create linked lists to keywords.  My service would use the user inputted keyword(s) and use the existing website owners onsite search function to return all results as well as filtering out keywords in an 'exclude' list that the user would also provide.